PyCharm 2024.2 not running Django tests correctly
Our project has extensive unit tests derived from rest_framework.test's APITestCase. This has always worked well - right-clicking on any Test file, class, or method, and selecting run has always generated a test configuration which has run the test effectively. But with the release of PyCharm 2024.2, this has mysteriously stopped working. I'm wondering if I'm overlooking a configuration setting or file somewhere.
I have 2024.1.7 and 2024.2.4 both installed currently. In 2024.1.7, the test command issued by PyCharm is of this form, which works:
python -u /home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm/django_test_manage.py test tests.api.test_my_code.MyCodeTest /opt/my-project-path

In 2024.2.4, I get this command instead:
python -u /home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm/django_test_manage.py /opt/my-project-path tests.api.test_my_code.MyCodeTest /Users/apollo/code/my-project-path

I'm using a Vagrant virtual machine on my Mac to run my local server code. /opt/my-project-path is the path in the virtual server, while /Users/apollo/code/my-project-path is the path on my Mac. But more importantly, where did the word test go in this command, and how do I get it back?? The django_test_manage.py execution quite sensibly responds with:
Unknown command: '/opt/my-project-path'

